# Clarifying Blender skeleton animation and OpenGL

Tags: game-engine, rigging, mathematics

I'm looking into implememting skeleton animations. I use Blender to create the armatures, export them using the IQM file format (Inter Quake Model). 
My first steps are to make sure that I'm getting the right values in my openGL application.

I created a very basic model in blender:
[image]

When I print the local matrix of the root bone in Blender I see:

```
>>> bpy.data.armatures[0].bones[0].matrix_local

Matrix(((1.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0)))
```

Which seems to be a 90º rotation around the X-axis. 
**Why does the matrix_local of this particular bone given me a 90º rotation around the X-axis?**

Another question I have is, when I convert this matrix to a quaternion in Blender,
I get `(0.7071068286895752, 0.7071068286895752, 0.0, 0.0)`
(w,x,y,z). Though when I create my own quaternion with a 90º rotation around X, I also get `(0.707107, 0.707107, 0.000000, 0.000000)` (wxyz), though when I convert that back to a matrix using my own math lib, I get:

```
1.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00
0.00,  0.00,  1.00,  0.00
0.00, -1.00,  0.00,  0.00
0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  1.00
```

It would be great if someone could clarify this a bit!

Thanks

Comment: Could this be related to Blender being Z up, while many other 3D graphics applications and game engines are Y up?

Comment: @SixthOfFour if it was related to Z-up instead of Y-up it doesn't explain why the bone has an rotation in the first place right?

Comment: @SixthOfFour, good catch with the axis thing but it looks like it could be that Y and Z are reversed.   I'd first try to multiply both of them both by -1.0.  before swizzling anything.  You should be able to diagnose if Y and Z need to be swapped by rotating the root bone by 20 degrees along one of those axis.  Right now with both of them at (+/- 1.0) it's hard to tell.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Thanks for your coment, but instead of trying out different things I want to understand why I'm getting these values.

Comment: (1(sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2), 0, 0) does correspond exactly to the difference between Z up and Y up. Does it have the rotation **before** you export, or does it show up after you import it (either back into Blender or into some other application)? If it does the former, I cannot explain it, if it does the latter, it may simply be that Blender converts it by rotating rather than switching the coordinates.

Comment: That should be **shifting** not switching.

Comment: What I meant is that from looking at the resulting Transform Matrix it looks as if the Y and Z axis both need to be multiplied by -1.0.  There is no common standard in 3D graphics for which direction an axis should point towards regarding positive and negative.  Swizzling is when you convert position.xyz to something like position.xzy(this has an effect similar to a 90 rotation of the grid system) but often it's also necessary to multiply one or more of the axis' by -1.0 to reverse their direction in regards to positive/negative.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I am fairly new to 3D graphics, been at it for about a year and a half, and I've only ever used Blender for it, so I've not really encountered any real problems with axis orientation. On the few occasions I have seen it, it has been Y up and Z towards me, as opposed to Blender's Z up and Y away from me. My comments above were based on that. You probably know more about this than I do.

Comment: @SixthOfFour You're doing well for only having been at it for a short time.

Comment: Y up and Z towards me is the GPU manufacture's standard for OpenGL/GLSL.  My experience has been that for 3D graphics programs that started around the 90's, it is really hit and miss when it comes to axis convention.  Packages made in the past few years are more likely to use the GPU convention.  For normal maps baked with Blender Internal, I just swap Y and Z and multiply them both by -1.0 in the shader.  For the models, I rotate the entire scene by 90 degrees after I establish the projection matrix.  It saves me from the confusion and hassle of altering the mesh plus normals maps.

Comment: I figured out what the rotations mean. In blender meshes/vertices etc.. are in a space with Z-up. Armatures/bones are in Y-up. A bone, aligns with the Y axis, from head to tail. So to align the bone with my mesh, blender needs to rotate it 90º around X, which makes sense now.  Thanks everyone for their input.

Answer (score 1):

A rotation matrix tells you what to do with the components of a vector indicating the position of a point.  For a rotation around X, a vector along X does not change.  At 90 degrees, a vector along Y becomes a vector along Z, and a Z vector becomes -Y.  Rotation about X causes Z and Y to intermingle.

The fourth row/column do not matter - that is an artifact of doing 3D geometry in projective coordinates. We sometimes call it 'w' and normally just set it to 1.0 and leave it there.  The thing being rotated is a vector representing a direction or position.

The rotation matrix does the rotating.  Generally, it intermingles components in a two-dimensional subspace, and leaves a one dimension subspace, the axis of rotation, alone.

---

Quaternions, in contrast, are better thought of (sometimes) as the thing being rotated. No, not rotated, but "acted upon".   For quaternions act a bit odd.

The First Quirky Principle of Quaternions is that if we want to deal with a rotation of (theta) degrees, we work on the quaternion by half that angle.

The Second Quirky Principle: instead of having three components like a vector, we add a fourth, conventionally called 'W'. We may call it the "scalar component".  All four components are involved when we "act upon" the quaternion in a way corresponding to some rotation.  I've taken to calling this action "Spotation" for "Spinor Rotation" - in quantum physics, we use "spinors" which amount to the same thing as quaternions.

Consider a rotation about X, as before.  The Y and Z components intermingle, as with a vector, but at half the rotation angle. That is, a 90 degree X rotation which would swap Y and Z (minus signs as appropriate) for a vector, will look like a 45 degree rotation has acted upon the Y and Z components of a quaternion.  (Does Blender S.E allow LaTeX?)

```
Y' = 1/sqrt(2) Y - 1/sqrt(2) Z
Z' = 1/sqrt(2) Y + 1/sqrt(2) Z
```

But according to the second quirky principle of quaternions, the "spotation" action intermingles the scalar 'W' component and the X component in a similar manner.

```
W' = 1/sqrt(2) W - 1/sqrt(2) X
X' = 1/sqrt(2) W + 1/sqrt(2) X
```

The exact algebraic rules for doing this were invented by Hamilton in the late 19th Century.

Generally, a rotation about any axis **A** will correspond to a "spotation" about the same axis **A**, but while a given vector that happens to be parallel to **A** will remain unaffected by the rotation, the corresponding spotation acting on a quaternion whose vector part is along **A**, *will* be affected.

We can relate quaternions to rotations by starting off with a quaternion which is pure scalar, that is,  w,x,y,z = 1,0,0,0.   Then some rotation **R** about some axis **A** by angle (theta) will act on the quaternion by converting the W component, being the only nonzero component, into a scalar + vector parallel to **A**.

---

Note that one consequence of the Two Quirky Principles of Quaternions is that a 180 degree rotation about any axis, which will just negate any vector perpendicular to the axis of rotation, corresponds to a spotation which looks like a 90 degree rotation. If the axis is along X Y or Z, it cleanly trades (with minus signs as needed) between W, Z, Y or Z.   This is a key point to why interpolation of orientation works so nicely with quaternions, as discovered by Ken Shoemake in the 1980s.  Negation of a vector does not offer any natural way to find a half-way point, but quaternions provide that nice hint.

Another interesting consequence is that a 360 rotation, easily confused with "no operation", corresponds to a 180 degree spotation - negation of all four components of the spinor. I mean, quaternion.  Two different quaternions describe the same orientation of an object.  That sometimes leads to some problems when animating spinning, tumbling, rolling objects, but easily fixed by flipping the sign of a quaternion somewhere in the timeline.

This also describes the strange antics of quantum particles such as electrons. As a theoretical physicist, I could blabber on and on about how all this arises from deep and beautiful mathematical relations between the rotation group in three dimensions, SO(3), and its double-covering group SU(2), and elegant math using "multivectors", and more, but that's getting off-topic for this site...

(Note: "Quirky Principles of Quaternions" is a phrase I made up on the spot just now, to avoid dealing with any real math. You won't find it in any textbook.)